# Excel 2013, SUMIFS formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, spreadsheet

I think I need to use a SUMIFS function for this but I am not positive. I have a list of codes:

All of these codes are in a category of downtime, each code also has minutes 5,10,15,40,65 etc. My sheet has all these codes in columns going across for that day, I need the total minutes for the downtime. The sum if works for my other categories that only have one code but I can't figure out how to make the multiple criteria work, I don't really have multiple criteria. It's just if you see FP put that in the downtime and add the minutes.
[image][image]

Comment: Can you post a screen shot showing your data organization?

Comment: I wish I could, I am not allowed as i do not have enough points for this site.

Comment: Maybe I need to nest this into a Vlookup? My reference data is on a hidden sheet, that is where I am trying to get the formula to recognize what code goes in each category.

Comment: So are you wanting to calculate v6 without having to calculate the subtotals shown in V3:V5, because there are actually many more than just three possible downtime codes?

Comment: No...that's not it....But I still don't understand exactly which values you are trying to calculate.  Now that you have a picture can you add detail?  (For example _Down time codes are "AR, CP, CG, PL, FP and LM."  Cell Y18 should display the total value of cells in row4 that are under one of these codes in row 3, in this case that would be ###)_

Comment: What you are seeing is one shift of production for a machine. They ran 3 different work orders, etc...So there are codes, here is the list (added in original question) All the codes are put into a category for production. I am trying to add the codes for each category, my goal is to know how much time was running, how much time was downtime. The categories that only have 1 code were easy to get added with a SumIF, I was thinking for the categories with multiple codes I could use SumIFS but I am not getting it to work. It isn't working though. Data picture above in question.

Comment: So is everything except "TR" considered run time?  If so, `=SUMIF(F3:T3,"<>TR",F4:T4)` ?  I must be missing something here.  What answer are you hoping to get with the example data in the screenshot?

Comment: TR = Run Time, the only code for Run Time is TR

Comment: So the little snippet of code I proposed should work, then - it checks the range for cells that are NOT TR (run time) and adds up the corresponding values for hits.

Comment: Ugh, i see my screen shot is cut off.... UT is the Downtime category, This has many codes... AM
DH
EL
FI
FM
FP
IM
LM
MC
ME
PL
SE
TP
AP
N/A
  The problem/ solution i need is for this when there is mulitple codes, I need a formula to say there is AP, TP, CG all those are UT(downtime) now add all the times and give me the total amount of downtime...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the sheet wherein you stored your list of codes is called *CodeSheet*

`={SUM(IF(IFERROR(MATCH(f3:t3,CodeSheet!$A$8:$A$22,0),0)>0,f4:t4))}`

*This is an array formula.  Enter it without the curly braces, and hit control-shift-enter.  Excel will put the curly braces in for you.*

**How it works:**

- `MATCH(f3:t3,CodeSheet!$A$8:$A$22,0)`
  [image]

*CodeSheet!$A$8:$A$22* is your list of codes that are in the downtime category.
Match looks for each of the values in f3:t3, and finds their position on that list (if any).  Since it is an array formula, it can return an array like this
`{#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,#N/A,11, #N/A,#N/A,....`
Everywhere it didn't get a match, it returns an error.  In other places, it give the place on the list where the match was encountered.  (In this case, "PL" was the 11th downtime code in the list)

We want to throw out the errors, so we wrap it in `iferror`

- `IFERROR(MATCH(F1:M1,CodeSheet!$A$8:$A$22,0),0)`
  [image]

Any of error values in that array that are replaced with 0. (FALSE)

output = `{0,0,0,0, 11, 0...`

Each non-zero value in our new array, we replace with the value in the corresponding cell of the minutes row:

- `IF(IFERROR(MATCH(F1:M1,CodeSheet!$A$8:$A$22,0),0)>0,F2:M2)`
  This replaces "11" with the value underneath the PL in row 4.
  output = `{0,0,0,0, 15, 0...`

[image]

Nothing left to do but sum it up!

Hope that helps.